# VBA dictionary <out of context> after Sub is run

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

I am trying to run the following code to create a dictionary that will then be used in a function to assign the functions parameter values depending on the dictionary key.

```
Option Explicit

Public b1 As Object
Public var1 As Variant
Public var2 As String
Public var3 As Variant

Sub CreateDictionaries()
    Set b1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    b1.Add "key1", 0.009
    b1.Add "key2", 0.011
    b1.Add "key3", 0.014
    b1.Add "key4", 0.025
    b1.Add "key5", 0.045
End Sub

Public Function MyFunction(var1, var2, var3)
    If var1 <= 5 Then
        MyFunction = b1.Item(var2) * var1* var3
    ElseIf var1 > 5 And var1 <= 10 Then
        MyFunction = b1.Item(var2) * (var1 - 5) * var3
    ElseIf var1 > 10 Then
        MyFunction  = b1.Item(var2) * (var1 - 10) * var3    
    End If
End Function
```

Although this worked initially, after I temporarily changed the Sub to Static Sub it stopped working. Changing it back to what it was in its last working condition has not fixed the problem. Restarting VBA and running the code as a new module also haven't worked.

While debugging I can see in the Watch window that the dictionary b1 is created as it should, however after the Sub finishes it takes the value "out of context". It doesn't make any sense, and it's now driving me crazy! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- Add a reference to the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** library; this will allow you to use the actual types, instead of plain Object:

  ```
  Public b1 As Scripting.Dictionary
  ```
- You *could* initialize the dictionary using the `New` syntax:

  ```
  Public b1 As New Scripting.Dictionary
  ```

  although this will only create the dictionary; it won't fill it; which brings us the the next point.
- AFAIK, in VBA there is no constructor method for modules. So you'll have to verify that the dictionary has been filled, and perhaps test for initialization as well, before you try to use it:

  ```
  Public b1 As Scripting.Dictionary

  Sub InitializeDictionary()
      If Not b1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
      Set b1 = New Scripting.Dictionary
      b1.Add "key1", 0.009
      b1.Add "key2", 0.011
      b1.Add "key3", 0.014
      b1.Add "key4", 0.025
      b1.Add "key5", 0.045
  End Sub

  Public Function MyFunction(var1, var2, var3)
      InitializeDictionary
      If var1 <= 5 Then
          MyFunction = b1.Item(var2) * var1* var3
      ElseIf var1 > 5 And var1 <= 10 Then
          MyFunction = b1.Item(var2) * (var1 - 5) * var3
      ElseIf var1 > 10 Then
          MyFunction  = b1.Item(var2) * (var1 - 10) * var3    
      End If
  End Function
  ```
- The `Static` keyword won't make a difference here. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278504.aspx), the `Static` keyword on a `Function` or `Sub`:

  > indicates that the `Sub` procedure's local variables are preserved between calls. *The `Static` attribute doesn't affect variables that are declared outside the `Sub`, even if they are used in the procedure.*

  and in this case the `b1` variable has been declared outside of the `Sub`.

  Using the `Static` statement to declare module-level variables (such as `b1`) will also have no effect -- in either case the value will last until the code is reset. It only makes a difference when declaring variables within a procedure.
- Regarding the Watch window and the variables `<out of context>`, when you add a Watch in the VBA IDE, you need to specify the context as `<all procedures>` and `<all modules>`. Otherwise, the Watch variable will only be evaluated when the debugger is stopped within the selected module, and within the selected procedure.

Comment: It's not a good idea to auto-instance object variables: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx

Comment: @CallumDA If all you want is to ensure that the variable refers to a `Dictionary` and is not `Nothing`, then I don't see any reason not to use the auto-instance syntax -- every usage will in fill the variable with the new `Dictionary`. It's only when initialization is more complex than simply creating a new `Dictionary` -- e.g. filling it in with certain values -- that auto-instancing is useless; as I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: In your code you write `If Not b1 Is Nothing` -- that's not going to work because you haven't created the Dictionary yet. Furthermore if you changed `Public b1 As New Dictionary` it still wouldn't work for the same reason (see link). FYI I'm not just guessing at this, I tested your code and it didn't work.

Comment: @CallumDA I'd forgotten the `Set b1 = New Scripting.Dictionary` within `InitializeDictionary`. Fixed.

Comment: @Zev Spitz Many thanks for your reply. Once I specified my Watches as <all procedures> I was able to find fix the problem, which embarrassingly enough was not due to the way I have constructed my dictionary, but rather due to not having declared var2 As String in the function. As undeclared, var2 is "variant" type and I guess this is not good enough when my dictionary keys are strings. I believe var2 as "variant" was picking up any keys from the dictionary therefore `b1.Item(var2)` was returning zero instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Static` `Dictionary` inside the function. The dictionary will be populated the first time you use the function but after that the values will be retained and the relevant code skipped.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MyFunction(var1, var2, var3)

    Static b1 As Object   
    If b1 Is Nothing Then
        Set b1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        b1.Add "key1", 0.009
        b1.Add "key2", 0.011
        b1.Add "key3", 0.014
        b1.Add "key4", 0.025
        b1.Add "key5", 0.045
    End If

   If var1 <= 5 Then
        MyFunction = b1.Item(var2) * var1* var3
    ElseIf var1 > 5 And var1 <= 10 Then
        MyFunction = b1.Item(var2) * (var1 - 5) * var3
    ElseIf var1 > 10 Then
        MyFunction  = b1.Item(var2) * (var1 - 10) * var3    
    End If
End Function
```

---

As others have pointed out, it's usually better to *early-bind* your variables. Which means if you know you want a `Dictionary` object, avoid declaring a `Object` first and then converting it to a `Dictionary` when you can just declare it as a `Dictionary` right away. To do this you need to include the reference to the Scripting Runtime Library and use:

```
Dim b1 As Scripting.Dictionary
Set b1 = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

**Do not** use the single `As New` statement below because it can cause unwanted errors [(more here)](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx)

```
Dim b1 As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Building the dictionary within the function works very nicely.